# How can you use a symbol from SVG defs.svg as background image in CSS?

Tags: css, svg, background

I'm trying to use a symbol from my defs.svg as a background image in CSS, as opposed to a direct path to an individual SVG file.

So instead of:

```
background: url(spoon.svg);
```

I want to do something like this:

```
background: url(defs.svg#spoon);
```

With #spoon being a symbol in defs.svg with id="spoon". Unfortunately, this isn't working for me. Has anyone come across a solution that doesn't involve custom JS/etc?

Comment: You'd need to refer to the symbol via a use tag and that means you can't do it via background CSS. You could put the use tags in the svg file itself and display them in a grid then display part of the grid via the svg viewspec capability, kind of like the spritesheet concept.

Comment: This is very good to know, I was having trouble finding a definitive answer online. Thanks @RobertLongson

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to define `view` and `use` tags inside your defs.svg so CSS would know where to look and what to show.

So, for example, say you have inside your SVG a symbol defined as this:

```
<symbol id="poop" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- Your shapes here -->
</symbol>
```

And *before* closing the `svg` tag, you must add the `view` and `use` defining tags:

```
<view id="poop-view" viewBox="0 0 100 100" /><!-- This ID used here is what you'll use in your CSS! -->
<use xlink:href="poop" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0"></use>
```

Note that at this point, you can open your raw SVG file in a browser and it will show your drawing - before it showed blank!

And now you can set your SVG symbol in your CSS:

```
div{background-image:url("defs.svg#poop-view")} /* Remember, it's the ID used on your <view> def! */
```

Also, be sure your SVG includes a `xmlns:xlink` namespace on the opening tag, or it won't be supposed to work.

Disclaimer: I'm trying to use this setup at work hosting the SVG file on a server on my university, but for some reason this doesn't work (even SVG files won't show if `<?xml>`and `<!DOCTYPE>` tags are missing on the SVG), so be sure to check the sanity of your SVG file.

Find more about this on [Jennifer Hiller's codepen blog](https://codepen.io/jennhi/post/using-svg-symbols-as-css-backgrounds).

Comment: You should add 'xmlns:xlink' attribute in svg: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`